# Prove using integration that $polygon → circle\space \text{as}\space number\space of\space sides → infinity$

Tags: integration, euclidean-geometry, circles, polygons

Say we have a regular polygon $s$, with number of sides $n$:

Is there a way to prove that as $n → ∞,\space $then $s → circle$ using integration?

Comment: Unless you're using at least one of those two words with a non-standard meaning, a circle is NOT a polygon, and therefore there had better not be any proof that it is!

Comment: As someone who doesn't know that much about math, this question makes perfect sense. Given a hypothetical function, $p(n)$, which generates a regular polygon with number of sides, $n$: $lim_{n \to ∞} p(n) = \text{circle}$, right?

Comment: @Josh In the limit, the area and circumference of the polygon will converge to the area and circumference of a circle of equal diameter. The maximum distance between each point of the circle and the nearest point of the polygon converges to zero. The number of non-differentiable points on the circumference does _not_ converge to zero, and the measure of the portion of the circumference with zero curvature does not converge to zero either. So, some properties are satisfied in the limit, others are not. I think it's OK to say $s\to circle$ if you only care about the first set of properties.

Comment: @DavidK: Thanks. But a line segment of infinitesimal length is a point, isn't it? So a polygon with ∞ sides would actually be a collection of ∞ points, each one the same distance from the centre, just the same as a circle? And you're telling me that you can differentiate the points on a circle, but not the vertices of a polygon? Sorry if I'm sounding dumb here.

Comment: @Josh A line segment of _zero_ length is a point, and there are uncountably many of them on the circumference of a circle, which is more than merely "infinitely" many. To make a line segment of infinitesimal but non-zero length, you might resort to non-standard analysis; I don't know enough about non-standard analysis to be sure what happens then, but the transfer principle suggests to me that we still don't get all the circle properties in the limit.

Comment: The vertices of a polygon are non-differentiable in the sense that the circumference doesn't go in a single well-defined direction there, whereas it does do so everywhere on a circle.

Comment: But the differences between the "infinite sided polygon" and the circle don't matter much if you don't try to use one of the non-converging properties of the polygon to prove something about the circle. Area and length of circumference work fine, for example.

Comment: @David: I think I'm starting to get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Denote length of side of a regular polygon as $s$, and the radius as $r$.

Making a triangle for each of the $n$ sides in the polygon:

$$s / 2 = r \times \sin\left(\frac{180}{n}\right)$$

Then the perimiter of the polygon is the length of each side times the number of sides: $$s \times n = 2\times r \times \sin\left(\frac{180}{n}\right) \times n$$

Taking the limit as the number of sides goes to infinity:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left[2\times r \times \sin\left(\frac{180}{n}\right) \times n\right] = 2\pi r \quad \blacksquare$$

For a given radius, we want to prove that as the number of sides approaches infinity, the perimeter of polygon approaches a circumference of a circle with the same radius, the two shapes are as indistinguishable as we desire to make them by drawing the polygon with n sides as close to infinity as needed.

**If-then proof:**

If a regular polygon has infinite sides, then it is a circle.

If the limit of the perimeter of a regular polygon approaches a circumference of 2 * Pi * r as the number of sides goes to infinity, then it is a circle.

Some would consider this "vacuous truth", because it is impossible to find a case where a polygon has infinite sides and is not a circle. The if-conditional is technically impossible, but the statement nonetheless resolves to true.

In terms of integrating, $s\times n$ is technically integrating infinitesimal sides of the same length $s$ over the perimeter of the polygon (in discrete as a summation): \Sum(x(s),{x,1,n}) = x1(s) + x2(s) + ... + xn(s) = lengthOfSide1 + lengthOfSide2 + ... = n * s. They are considered the same, akin to comparing arc length using rectification and infinitesimal calculus.

Comment: just a comment regarding the If-then proof, the definition "If a regular polygon has infinite sides, then it is a circle" imho I think it would need to be more specific: the apeirogon can have infinite sides and it will never be a circle. Some weeks ago by chance I asked about the differences between when the limit of the n-gon is a circle and when it is not, being an apeirogon. Here is the link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357158/trying-to-understand-the-limit-of-regular-polygons-circle-vs-apeirogon-vs-infi

Answer (score 0):

The pioneers of the calculus, including Leibniz, thought of a circle as an infinite-sided polygon, as the OP suggests. This turned out to be a fruitful idea, even though today we avoid this viewpoint. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518121/interesting-medieval-mathematics-lecture-activity-ideas/520250#520250) for aditional details.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the equation for the measure of each an a regular polygon:
$\frac{(n-2)180^\circ}{n} $

Now, consider the function :$$f(x)= \frac{(x-2)180}{x}$$
The limit of this function as $x$ approaches infinity is $180$.

As $x$ gets very large, the measure of the angles inside the polygon with that amount of sides gets closer and closer to $180$.

In fact, if you had a $1000$-gon, to the naked eye it would appear a circle. However, the slight deviation would make it a polygon, not a circle, since the interior angle measures would be $179.64^\circ $

So this raises a question: When $x$ is infinity, do we end up with a circle? As $x$ becomes arbitrarily large, the resulting polygon would appear more and more similar to a circle, but never actually a circle. When we have an infinite number of sides, the resulting figure is not a polygon, but a circle.

When x is infinity, $f(x)$ is $180$. You might claim that a polygon with interior angle measures of 180 degrees is not possible, and you'd be right. 
In fact, this is so impossible that the resulting figure isn't a polygon; it can't be. Instead, we are left with a circle.

So a circle is not a polygon with an infinite number of sides, because a circle isn't a polygon by any means.

However, you should check out the *apeirogon*, the geometric figure with an actual infinite number of sides.

Answer (score 0):

The statement "as $n\to\infty,$ then $s\to\text{circle}$" is much too informal to lead at all to something that is provable.

The same goes with "$\lim_{n\to\infty}p(n)=\text{circle}$" (in the comments).

Comment: It is surely much too informal to clearly and unambiguously lead to something provable, but that doesn't mean there is no reasonable interpretation that is provable.  For instance, one such statement is that (appropriately scaled) regular $n$-gons converge to a circle in the Gromov-Hausdorff topology.

Comment: @EricWofsey: What's the use bombarding the OP with that ?